# Is this best practice? Checking if variable defined or assign null

Tags: javascript, typescript, best-fit

```
const pictureEntity = updateUserDto?.picture

  ? await this.filesService.find(updateUserDto.picture)

  : null;

if (pictureEntity) {

  const pictureEntity.url = await this.filesService.getFileUrl(pictureEntity);

}
```

Is this the correct way to assign the value to pictureEntity? Basically if property picture is not defined, I'm not supposed to use the service find in filesService because typeORM will return the first value that it finds if property picture is null or undefined.

I was doing this:

```
if (updateUserDto?.picture) {
  const pictureEntity = await this.filesService.find(updateUserDto.picture);
}
```

but TS would complain because I'm declaring a variable inside an If.

Comment: You aren't declaring a variable in the 2nd snippet. You are only assigning to (possibly undefined) variable.

Comment: @idmean Thank you, I corrected it, I hadn't notice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
const pictureEntity = updateUserDto?.picture && await this.filesService.find(updateUserDto.picture);
```

If `updateUserDto` is `null` or `undefined`, `pictureEntity` will be `undefined`. Otherwise it will `await` your other promise.

**Edit:**

There's also no need for a `const` here:

```
if (pictureEntity) {

  const pictureEntity.url = await this.filesService.getFileUrl(pictureEntity);

}
```

You don't use `const` to create object properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set `pictureEntity` to a value only when `updateUserDto?.picture` is set, your original attempt was almost correct but you just need to define the variable outside of the `if` block before setting the value like this

```
let pictureEntity;
if (updateUserDto?.picture) {
  pictureEntity = await this.filesService.find(updateUserDto.picture);
}
```

Be aware that you will need to use `let` instead of `const` since you're now assigning to the variable after creation. Also note that the default value of `pictureEntity` will be `undefined` if `updateUserDto?.picture` is falsy

Comment: Yes, I thought of that! But I didn't want to declare and then use, because I'm using that value elsewhere, And I know for a fact that picture entity will be undefined if there is none